# ValidateScript and order of operations

Tags: powershell

I am not understanding why ValidateScript is not erroring out until the end..

```
param (
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory = $true,
        HelpMessage = "Specifies the email address that will manage the share drive to be created.")]
        [ValidateScript({
            if ($_.host -eq "domain.com") {
                return $true
            }
            else {
                Throw [System.Management.Automation.ValidationMetadataException] "Enter an email address ending with @domain.com"
            }
        })][Net.Mail.MailAddress]$EmailAddress,
    
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory = $true,
        HelpMessage = "Specifies the name of the share drive name to be created. Enter a shared drive name like prgm- and at least 2 letters. Example prgm-hi")]
    [ValidateScript({
            if ($_ -like "prgm-??*") {
                return $true
            }
            else {
                Throw [System.Management.Automation.ValidationMetadataException] "Enter a shared drive name like prgm- and at least 2 letters. Example prgm-hi"
            }
        })][string]$SharedDriveName
)
```

In this code snip sample above if the script is run the person will get past the `emailaddress` variable if it is wrong and than get to the error after all the variables are answered.

I am not understanding how to have the script stop right as someone makes a bad entry.

I assume, I will have to use something other than validate script but I am not sure what?

Comment: `ValidateScript` and all validation decorations are evaluated at runtime, __not in real time__.

Comment: Running as designed by PS then. Nothing I can do about it?

Comment: If you want in real time validation you can consider converting your function into a GUI app. Other than that you can convince whoever is using your function to input correct arguments via autocompletion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps surprisingly, **when PowerShell automatically prompts for values for missing mandatory parameters** (written as of PowerShell 7.3.2):

- it enforces the parameter data type *after each prompt*.
- but **performs *validation* - based on attributes such as [`ValidateScript()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ValidateScriptAttribute) - only *after ALL prompts have been answered***.

This makes for an awkward interactive experience, given that as a user you won't learn whether any of your inputs are valid until *all* of them have been provided.

I can't speak to the design intent - a *conceivable* reason for this evaluation order is to allow validation script blocks to also consider *other* parameter values; however, *in practice* you can *not* refer to other parameters inside a `[ValidateScript()]` script block.

On a general note, the automatic prompting mechanism has fundamental limitations - see [GitHub issue #7093](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7093).

---

**Workaround**:

You can **move prompting and validating into the *body* of your function (as well)**, where you get to control the execution flow - obviously, this requires extra work:

```bash
param (
  [Parameter(
    # Do NOT make the parameter mandatory, so that it can be prompted for
    # in the function body, but DO define a HelpMessage.
    HelpMessage = "Specify the email address that will manage the share drive to be created (must end in @sonos.com)"
  )]
  [ValidateScript({
      if ($_.host -eq 'sonos.com') {
        return $true
      }
      else {
        Throw "Enter an email address ending with @sonos.com"
      }
  })]
  [Net.Mail.MailAddress] $EmailAddress,
    
  [Parameter(
    # Do NOT make the parameter mandatory, so that it can be prompted for
    # in the function body, but DO define a HelpMessage.
    HelpMessage = "Specify the name of the share drive name to be created. Enter a shared drive name like prgm- and at least 2 letters. Example prgm-hi"
  )]
  [ValidateScript({
      if ($_ -like "prgm-??*") {
        return $true
      }
      else {
        Throw "Enter a shared drive name like prgm- and at least 2 letters. Example prgm-hi"
      }
  })]
  [string]$SharedDriveName
)

# If no values were provided any of the conceptually mandatory parameters,
# prompt for and validate them now.
# Infer which parameters are conceptually mandatory from the presence of a 
# .HelpMessage property.
$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
  # See if there's a .HelpMessage property value and, if so,
  # check if the parameter hasn't already been bound.
  $helpMessage = $_.Value.Attributes.Where({ $_ -is [Parameter] }).HelpMessage
  if ($helpMessage -and -not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey($_.Key)) {
    # Prompt now and validate right away, which happens implicitly when
    # the parameter variable is assigned to.
    while ($true) {
      try {
        Set-Variable -Name $_.Key -Value (Read-Host $helpMessage)
        break # Getting here means that validation succeeded -> exit loop.
      }
      catch { 
        # Validation failed: write the error message as a warning, and keep prompting.
        Write-Warning "$_"
      }
    }
  }
}

# ... all required arguments are now present and validated.
```

Note:

- The upside of this approach is that you can *keep prompting* until valid input is received (or the user aborts with <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>).